# How to call a method from a UserControl class?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a Windows Forms app and I would like to call a method in a UserControl class.

My method is placed in `Desktop`:

```
public Desktop(StringWrapper stringWrapper, AppConfigManager appConfigManager, RecoveryManager recoveryManager, IProfileManager profileManager, IScanPerformer scanPerformer, IScannedImagePrinter scannedImagePrinter)
{ 
  public void ScanDefault()
   {
     if (profileManager.DefaultProfile != null)
      {
        scanPerformer.PerformScan(profileManager.DefaultProfile, new ScanParams(), this, notify, ReceiveScannedImage());
        Activate();
      }
      else if (profileManager.Profiles.Count == 0)
      {
         ScanWithNewProfile();
      }
      else
      {
         ShowProfilesForm();
      }
   }
}
```

In the same folder I have created a User Control class:

```
public partial class UserControlTest : UserControl
{
    public UserControlTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In this `UserControlTest` I would like to call a `ScanDefault` method.

Comment: "How to call method from another class" if quite common beginner question. `ScanDefault()` is instance method, to call it you require instance of class containing it. But it's hard to recommend any solution (e.g. `new UserControl1().ScanDefault()`) because of lack of context, you didn't show enough code to demonstrate problem: where you want to call it, what this method (namely `Scan...()` methods) is doing, etc. Show your attempt and error you get.

Comment: Is `Desktop` a class or a method? Should it be `public class Desktop` without parameters, or `public void Desktop` with a sub function ScanDefault?

Comment: I have changed it like Olivier told and that way it works. I just can't call it from UserControl yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScanDefault() is an inline function.

It's like a local variable.

You can't call it from outside the scope of Desktop().

To call it, you must make it as a class method and add parameters you want to use in the signature.

```
public Desktop(StringWrapper stringWrapper,
               AppConfigManager appConfigManager,
               RecoveryManager recoveryManager,
               IProfileManager profileManager,
               IScanPerformer scanPerformer,
               IScannedImagePrinter scannedImagePrinter)
{
  ScanDefault(profileManager, scanPerformer);
}

public void ScanDefault(IProfileManager profileManager, IScanPerformer scanPerformer)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for help. I have done it this way, but now how to call it from UserControl?

Comment: You call it like any other class method: ScanDefault(profileManager, scanPerformer);